# cronjob in codeigniter using cpanel

Tags: codeigniter, cron, cpanel

My website hosting server is hostmonster.com.

My application uses codeigniter framework.

I have a code which sends emails to my users and I want to make it automatic.

I have used the cpanel of the hosting service and I tried to give the command as

```
php -q www.mysite.com/admin admin sendDailyEmail
```

my controller is admin and the method is sendDailyEmail and the controller is present inside the application/controllers/admin folder.

I have also set a reminder email to me whenever the cronjob is run.

The email subject reads

> Cron  php -q /home1/username/public_html/admin admin sendDailyEmail

and the body says

> No input file specified

Where do I go wrong.

I have never run cronjobs and this is my first time.
I am no good in giving command line instuctions too.

My admin sendDailyEmail code is as follows

```
function sendDailyEmail() {
    $data = $this->admin_model->getDailyData();
    foreach ($data as $u) {
    if($u->Daily){
     //if(!$u->Amount){
       if ($u->Email=='myemail@gmail.com') {

                $user['user_data']['FirstName'] = $u->FirstName;
                $user['user_data']['LastName'] = $u->LastName;
                $user['user_data']['Id']=$u->Id;

                $this->email->clear();
                $this->email->to($u->Email);
                $this->email->from('alerts@mysite.com', 'MySite');
                $this->email->subject("My Subject");
                $msg = $this->load->view('emails/daily_view', $user, true);
                $this->email->message($msg);
                if ($this->email->send())
                    $data['message'] = "Daily Emails has been sent successfully";
                else
                    $data['message'] = "Daily Emails Sending Failed";
            }
        }
    }
    $data['main_content']['next_view'] = 'admin_home_view';
    $this->load->view('includes/admin_template', $data);
}
```

Comment: I have removed the authentication but if i now copy paste the url, it just sends away an email to my users. 

I fear that if someone knows, they keep on sending emails just by using the url.

How do I restrict this. I am using codeigniter.

The cronjob is run through the cpanel.

previously i have this code in my sendDailyEmail

    if (!$this->session->userdata('variable'))
           redirect('admin/admin', 'refresh');

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `wget` and set the time for whatever you like:

```
wget http://www.mysite.com/admin/sendDailyEmail
```

You can also use `curl`:

```
curl --silent http://www.mysite.com/admin/sendDailyEmail
```

Comment: The cronjob is done and I got an email saying
** --2013-10-05 11:20:01--  http://www.mysite.com/admin/admin/sendDailyEmail
Resolving www.mysite.com... 66.147.240.184
Connecting to www.mysite.com|66.147.240.184|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 0 [text/html]
Saving to: `sendDailyEmail'

     0K                                                        0.00 =0s

2013-10-05 11:20:11 (0.00 B/s) - `sendDailyEmail' saved [0/0] **

But it did not send out the email

Comment: If you type `http://www.mysite.com/admin/sendDailyEmail` directly in the browser does it send the email?

Comment: Tried this in my shared hosting env and got "Permission Denied" for wget and "request has been blocked by Mod Security" for curl.

Answer (score 12):

**For CodeIgniter 2.2.0**

You can try this:

```
 php-cli /home/username/public_html/index.php controller method
```

or at your case

```
 php-cli /home/username/public_html/index.php admin sendDailyEmail
```

It works fine with me..
Cheers!

Comment: i'm going to try ..feedback you after few hours

Comment: this helped me. for some reason, cpanel doesn't run scripts with `php` binary, but with `php-cli`.

Answer (score 3):

Codeigniter sets up command line differently for running crons, etc.

Read:
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html

So you should run:

```
php index.php admin admin sendDailyEmail
```

(that may need adjusted; based on your code above)

Have a look at an article I just wrote that goes a little deeper into it all:

http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2013/10/setting-environment-vars-for-codeigniter-commandline

Answer (score 1):

Here's my example for the cron job on cpanel using Codeigniter 3 framework:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/user/public_html/project/index.php controller method
```

Credits to Shinerweb youtube channel
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pgc2vzrlwok

Answer (score 0):

i have facing same issue while, but following work for me

```
wget http://www.yoursite.com/controller/function
```